# error while using POSIXct to import data

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

this is my data and i want to import them so when i execute this command

```
  data.raw=read.xlsx(file=file.choose(),sheetName = "Amanda",header=TRUE,row.names=NULL)%>%
  +     mutate(date.re = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

i get the following error

```
   Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
   c("do not know how to convert 'function (x) ' to class “POSIXct”", "do not  know how to convert 'UseMethod(\"date\")' to class “POSIXct”")
```

here's my data   [data](https://1fichier.com/?c93veajs7x)

Comment: There is no `date` column in the data.frame.

Comment: The name of your `date` column is called `"Date"` maybe that's why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second line is the format you called in the function `as.POSIXct` is different from the format in your Excel sheet. Moreover, you have no column called `'date'` so it obviously doesn't work.

Your `dates` have the followed format : `"%Y/%m/%d"` and `as.POSIXct()` is not a function to modify the format so you have to use `format()` :

```
mutate(data.raw, date.re = format(data.raw$Date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Results :

```
           Date Article Quantite           Reference    date.re
1    2016-07-26  Amanda        1 CL-KG-1457603663478 26/07/2016
2    2016-07-26  Amanda        1    CL-KG-1469536211 26/07/2016
3    2016-07-26  Amanda        1 CL-KG-1457603860711 26/07/2016
4    2016-07-26  Amanda        2    CL-KG-1469537066 26/07/2016
5    2016-07-26  Amanda        2    CL-KG-1469128777 26/07/2016
```

and then you can use `as.POSIXct()` if you want but check what this function does.